# Generic type in Array?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I was trying to create a mockup app that shows some data as a list of buttons. I implemented everything but I'm facing this problem right now. I initialised an array and another class for the data.

```
-items.ts

  export class ItemPage {

  items: Item[] = [];

  constructor() {

    this.items.push(
      new Item(1, 'Apple', 'Green', 6, true));
    this.items.push(
      new Item(2, 'Banana', 'Yellow', 15, false));
  }
```

and the data class looks like this

```
-item.ts

export class Item {
  constructor(
    id: number,
    fruit: string,
    color: string,
    quantity: number,
    onStock: boolean,
  ) { }
}
```

I'm facing a problem with `items: Item[] = [];` when I run `ionic serve`. It says `Generic type 'Item' requires 2 type argument(s)` and `type Item<K extends string, T> = { [P in K]: T; } Construct a type with a set of properties K of type T`.
I tried to solve it but it  didn't help, does anyone has any Idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like `Item` is a reserved word/class in Ionic. Try changing your `Item` to a different name.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I still have the same problem

Comment: Item<any,any>[] perhaps?

Comment: Can you add the code changes you made to the question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly manage to reproduce the issue, but instead ending up with two empty objects. The error seems that you are not setting the properties in your class as `public`, so changing your class to:

```ts
export class Item {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public fruit: string,
    public color: string,
    public quantity: number,
    public onStock: boolean,
  ) { }
}
```

seemed to work fine: **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VFfmaW1KR9JIANJJ8REV?p=preview)**

**BUT** I highly suggest you should use interfaces instead, if you don't need to have functions in classes or some other reason. So I'd say you make interface:

```ts
export interface Item {
  id: number;
  fruit: string;
  color: string;
  quantity: number;
  onStock: boolean;
}

constructor(private navController: NavController) {
  this.items.push({id:1, fruit:'Apple', color:'Green', quantity:6, onStock:true});
  this.items.push({id:2, fruit: 'Banana',color:'Yellow',quantity:15,onStock:false})
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hey, yeah it worked thanks.
If I want to use the army in another class, how should I do it?

I tried this:

`export class Stats{

public stat: number;

 constructor(items: Item[]) {
    this.stat = items.length;
}
}`

But it kept giving me the same error `Generic type 'Item' requires 2 type argument(s)`

Comment: Since this solved your issue, would you kindly accept the answer :) But back to your question... what is *army* and what class is this `Stats` is it a new Class or what?

Comment: I really suggest you to use interfaces, but you again forgot to set `public` in your constructor... I suppose your class should look something like this: `export class Stats {public stat: number;constructor(public stat: number, public items: Item[]=[]) {this.stat = items.length; }}` :)

Comment: sorry I meant array, my bad. Yes this is a new class in a new file called `stats.ts`, and I want to use the array `items: Item[]=[]` in `items.ts` in the new class.

Comment: I really am not sure exactly what you mean with *I want to use the array items in items.ts*. Here is an example of implementing the new class together with the items... http://plnkr.co/edit/2bVy1f02oeh7NtyD16he?p=preview

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Have a good day/night/morning/evening depending on your timezone :D And happy coding!